# Avoid lifetime constraints on trait associated types

Tags: rust, lifetime

tl;dr:

Is there any way to remove the lifetime declaration from `ObjectInner` and move it to the `foo` method?

```rust
trait ObjectTrait {
    type Input;
    fn foo(&mut self, input: &mut Self::Input);
}

struct ObjectInner<'a> {
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

impl<'a> ObjectTrait for ObjectInner<'a>
{
    type Input = Mut<'a>;
    fn foo(&mut self, _input: &mut Self::Input) {}
}
```

---

Suppose I have the following trait definition (with an associated type `Input`):

```rust
trait ObjectTrait {
    type Input;
    fn foo(&mut self, input: &mut Self::Input);
}
```

I'm interested in implementing this trait for an object such that the type used for `Input` could potentially take a lifetime.

```rust
impl ObjectTrait for ObjectInner
{
    type Input = Mut<'a>;
    fn foo(&mut self, _input: &mut Self::Input) {}
}
```

This won't compile since lifetime `'a` hasn't been defined. It makes sense, and it provides two suggestions:

```rust
error[E0261]: use of undeclared lifetime name `'a`
  --> src/main.rs:13:22
   |
13 |     type Input = Mut<'a>;
   |                      ^^ undeclared lifetime
   |
help: consider introducing lifetime `'a` here
   |
13 |     type Input<'a> = Mut<'a>;
   |               ++++
help: consider introducing lifetime `'a` here
   |
11 | impl<'a> ObjectTrait for ObjectInner
   |     ++++
```

Define the lifetime either in the type or in the impl.

Defining them on the type is out of the question since this requires changing the trait definition, which doesn't make sense for users of the trait without use for this lifetime.

Defining it on the impl makes more sense, and if done naively:

```rust
impl<'a> ObjectTrait for ObjectInner
{
    type Input = Mut<'a>;
    fn foo(&mut self, _input: &mut Self::Input) {}
}
```

I get the following error/help message:

```rust
error[E0207]: the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/main.rs:15:6
   |
15 | impl<'a> ObjectTrait for ObjectInner
   |      ^^ unconstrained lifetime parameter
```

I need to put a constraint on the lifetime. The only way I know how to do it is by extending the `ObjectInner` to have the following definition:

```rust
struct ObjectInner<'a> {
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

impl<'a> ObjectTrait for ObjectInner<'a>
{
    type Input = Mut<'a>;
    fn foo(&mut self, _input: &mut Self::Input) {}
}
```

This already works and is the best solution I've found so far.

**I wonder if there is a way to move this constraint outside of the struct definition to the declaration of the `foo` method.** I feel this should be possible, given that if I wouldn't be implementing a trait, I could make this with:

```rust
impl ObjectInner {
    fn bar<'a>(&mut self, input: &mut Mut<'a>) {}
}
```

Comment: No, this is not possible without changing the trait.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman isn't this possible due to a limitation of rust, or am I expressing my intent in the wrong way, and there is a way to go around this somehow?

Comment: I don't know what is your intent, so I don't know if you're expressing it the wrong way.